# Indirect modification of overloaded element of SimpleXMLElement has no effect

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing, simplexml

I have a page into my site where I have to parse an xml and insert result into an array.
But when I try to insert array rooms I have this error:

```
Indirect modification of overloaded element of SimpleXMLElement has no effect
```

The error is in this line:

```
$hotel_array[$id]['rooms'][$i] = $room_array;
```

This is my code:

```
$hotel_array = array(); 
//$xml->data is a valid xml parsed with simpleXML
foreach ($xml->DATA as $entry){
foreach ($entry->HOTEL_DATA as $entry2){
    $id = (string)$entry2->attributes()->HOTEL_CODE;
    if($entry2->attributes()->HOTEL_CODE=='YYG'){
         $exist = 0;
         if (array_key_exists('YYG', $hotel_array))
        $exist = 1;

         $hotel_array[$id] = $entry2->attributes()->HOTEL_CODE;
             $i=0;
         foreach($entry2->ROOM_DATA as $room){
        $room_array = array();
        $room_array['id'] = $room->attributes()->CCHARGES_CODE;
        $room_array['code'] = $room->attributes()->ROOM_CODE;
        $room_array['name'] = utf8_decode($room->ROOM_NAME);
>attributes()->NO_OF_EXTRA_BEDS;
        $hotel_array[$id]['rooms'][$i] = $room_array;
        $i++;
            }
}
}
```

Comment: What is your question? ***I know that PHP has such an error message and I know that PHP tells it to a programmer who used SimpleXMLElement in a way that is not possible.*** Just the wish to not see this error message ***will not make it go away***. So what exactly to you want to learn about?

Comment: I also simplified your code so it's better to read. There was much room for improvement. Compare with your previous version for the differences.

Comment: @hakre Editing the code in a question to make it better seems an odd thing to do - if there are problems in the code, then fixing those problems is part of an answer, not the question. The question seemed clear to me: "why am I getting this error message when I run this code?".

Comment: @hakre In fact, I'm pretty sure your edit eliminates the problem which led to the question in the first place, so I've rolled it back. Feel free to add it as an answer, but as a version of the question it makes no sense.

Comment: I'm not so sure it eliminated the question of OP, however OP can also compare his version against my change in the edit history. should both work. thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @hakre It didn't necessarily do exactly what the OP wants - I'm not at all clear what that is - but it did remove the error message they reported, which was due to `$hotel_array[$id]` being a SimpleXML object not an array.

Comment: yes OP re-used the variable. I've seen that as well and you already suggest a solution in your answer I see!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first problem you are seeing is that this line is not doing quite what you want:

```
$hotel_array[$id] = $entry2->attributes()->HOTEL_CODE;
```

Whenever you access a child element or attribute of a SimpleXML object, what you get back is another SimpleXML object. So at the end of this statement, `$hotel_array[$id]` points to a SimpleXML object. Then when you try to assign other details to `$hotel_array[$id]`, PHP thinks you are trying to modifying the XML itself in an unsupported way, leading to the error you're seeing.

What I think you actually want is to get the *content* of that attribute, as a plain PHP string. The way to do that is to cast to string with `(string)$variable`:

```
$hotel_array[$id] = (string)$entry2->attributes()->HOTEL_CODE;
```

However, you then have a second problem: `$hotel_array[$id]` is now a string, but a few lines later you try to treat it as an array:

```
$hotel_array[$id]['rooms'][$i] = $room_array;
```

Looking at the code, `$id` is already set to `(string)$entry2->attributes()->HOTEL_CODE`, and is stored as the key of the `$hotel_array` entry, so I'm not sure why you need to assign it again at all, but if you do, it can't go in the same place as the array containing the `['rooms']` key. Instead, you want one of these lines:

```
# Just create an empty hash with the key as the hotel code
$hotel_array[$id] = array();

# Add the hotel code into the array, next to the 'rooms' key
$hotel_array[$id]['code'] = (string)$entry2->attributes()->HOTEL_CODE;

# Above combined into one array initialisation, including empty 'rooms' array
$hotel_array[$id] = array(
    'code' => (string)$entry2->attributes()->HOTEL_CODE,
    'rooms' => array()
);
```

Comment: I need this structure because I have an array where can contain many times for example the key 'YYG' and if I found this key I want to insert it like an array into a jey of its name I don't want many array with ID inside YYG I want a unique array with key YYG with its child

Comment: I wanna push an array inside array with key (YYG the code) when its code is YYG

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. If the key is always `'YYG'`, then it will only exist once - you can't have two keys with the same name. If there are many entries with the same key, you'll have to nest a numeric array inside the associative array - something like `$hotel_array[$id][] = array('rooms' => $rooms_array)`

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like you are trying to set an attribute (`['rooms']`) on a SimpleXML element which already represents an attribute itself (`$hotel_array[$id]`).

Maybe I don't get what you are up to, but shouldn't $hotel_array($id) be a plain array in the first place (`$hotel_array[$id] = array();` and that's it)? Then you could build a nested array inside without a problem.

Comment: I only want to create an array like: $array['YYG']['rooms'][0]

Comment: Then don't assign a SimpleXML element to $array['YGG'] (that's what you do in the line `$hotel_array[$id] = $entry2->attributes()->HOTEL_CODE;`). That line is causing the error message.

Comment: how can I solve then?

Comment: Just as I said in my answer above. Assign an empty array instead of a SimpleXML element, then nest other arrays inside of it.

Comment: I have insert  $hotel_array = array(); and $hotel_array['rooms'][$i] = array(); same error